# how to find curl local(client) certificate in linux

Tags: linux, curl

When I use curl to get https url,if I don't use '--cert' option,which certificate file will be used by default.

Comment: None, a normal https request relies on the _server side certificate_ to be validated. Client side certificates are optional and actually very rare.

Comment: If use no client certificate, how to encrypt client data @arkascha

Comment: You do not need a client side certificate to encrypt data. Those are two separate things. A client side certificate is used to identify a unique client for the purpose of authorization. The encryption of the request payload is based on the server side certificate.

Comment: Think you ,but why you add a comment instead of an answer for this question. @arkascha

Comment: Didn't occur to me that this is your actual question, I expected something else to emerge behind that question ;-)

Comment: I added an answer below based on the comments here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal https request relies on the server side certificate to be validated. Client side certificates are optional and actually very rare. So the answer to your question is: "none".

You do not need a client side certificate to encrypt data. Those are two separate things. A client side certificate is used to identify a unique client for the purpose of authorization. The encryption of the request payload is based on the server side certificate.

Comment: It's usefull for me.